# Можно ли использовать в jsoncpp для очистки arrayValue вместо clear

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

Использую в работе библиотеку jsoncpp. Созданный ранее массив объектов можно очистить с помощью `clear`.

```
Json::Value value;
...
value.clear();
```

Можно ли использовать для очистки вместо clear arrayValue? И в чем разница?

```
Json::Value value;
...
value = Json::arrayValue;
```

В отладчике адреса и в том и в другом случае одни и те же.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю не стоит.

Разница в количестве операций.

Если в первом случае вызывается всего лишь:

```
void Value::clear() {
...
}
```

то во втором:
сперва будет создан объект, т.е. вызовется конструктор:

```
Value::Value(ValueType vtype) {
...
}
```

затем оператор =

```
Value& Value::operator=(Value other) {
....
}
```

и все что он тянет.

Comment: Т.е. Вы полагаете, что в первом случае не происходит присвоения старым объектам никаких значений? Так происходит. Доступ к ним остается валидным, но они обнулены. Но, перед обнулением, думаете ничего не создается для заполнения в отличие от второго варианта?

Comment: судя по [исходникам](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/blob/master/src/lib_json/json_value.cpp) ничего не создается.

Comment: А почему Вы считаете, что во втором случае будет создаваться объект? Ведь arrayValue - это член enum. А в операторе присваивания,  который Вы привели не польностью, идет swap, а не копирование. Но, как я указал в вопросе, адреса не меняются. А при swap они бы изменились.